# HTML Table for image overlapping background

Tags: html, css, email, html-email

I'm trying to create a CTA button that has an image overlapping it for an HTML email I am coding.

I have a plan of action for building it, but it doesn't seem to work across browsers and email clients. It looks great in Google Chrome, but it starts to break in many other browsers and clients (Codepen for example)

I put my code, a screenshot of what I am trying to create, along with a wireframe for reference in this codepen. Where am I going wrong?

`enter code here`Here is my [codepen](http://codepen.io/vcgbkirschner/pen/jrvoyy).

Thanks all in advance!

Comment: Why not make the whole thing one image? HTML email is a pain.

Comment: Why do you use half pixels? Most devices can't render half pixels.

Comment: Hmm, I was not aware that some devices don't do half pixels. Ty for the info.  In terms of making an image, yes I could do that, but I want to try and deliver this since HTML text looks so much crisper

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this it should work:

```html
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
    <td width="118" style="width: 118px;">
      <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
        <tr>
          <td width="118" height="9" style="font-size: 9px; line-height: 9px; height: 9.5px;"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td bgcolor="#0069aa" height="48" style="color: #ffffff;font-style: italic;font-weight: bold;text-align: center;font-size: 10px !important;background-color: #0069aa;line-height: 16px !important; font-size: 15.5px !important;">
            Download
            <br />FREE e-book</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
    <td width="54" height="57" bgcolor="#0069aa" style="width: 54px; background-color:#0069aa; vertical-align:top;">
      <img width="54" src="http://www.camping-trafoi.com/pricelist/dog.gif" alt="" style="display:block;margin:0;padding:0;">
    </td>
    <td width="8" height="57.5" style="height: 57.5px;width: 8px;">
      <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
        <tr>
          <td height="9.5" style="height: 9.5px; font-size: 9.5px; line-height: 9.5px;"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td height="48" bgcolor="#0069aa" style="height: 48px; background-color: #0069aa;font-size: 48px; line-height: 48px;">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```